# Mule Facebook connector fails behind a proxy-server

Tags: facebook, mule

I get this error when I use the Mule Facebook connector.

Failed to invoke publishMessage. Message payload is of type: String

I see other say that the connector does not work behind a proxy server. I hope not because we use then for security. Is this fixed or not ?

Comment: That is just a general Mule error message. Do you see anything more specific in the Studio console/logs?

Comment: Aaa OK I see. I got this error. There is no access token stored under the key \\jaco.fourie.xxxx. You need to call ,authorize. message processor. Sorry for these questions. As you can tell I am new to Mule and Facebook development.

Comment: I got it working. I had 2 problems. That is what you get when you copy code from the internet ;-) 

1) Had some / in the MEL code for the session vars and 2) I had to give it a profile to post the message to. It works now that for all the help